# how to call jquery click function from other jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to call jquery **click** function from other jquery function.

i tried by using trigger function it is not working.

Here is my jquery function

```
$('#index1').click(function(event){
    $('#index2').trigger('click');
});

$('#index2').click(function(event){
   alert("Hello");
});
```

i want to call **#index2** function from **#index1** function.

Comment: `.trigger()` should work. Are you trying to click element or simply execute the click handler? You can try `$('#index2').get(0).click()`

Comment: It works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/tk6y0x81/

Comment: Your code works, so?! If no, then obviously you aren't binding events

Comment: Try replacing line 2 with $('#index2').click();

Comment: your code is just perfect, just check if you have added a Jquery library or not.

Comment: **$('#index2').get(0).click()** worked. Thank you all

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working example:

**Be sure you have added a jquery library**

```js
$('#index1').click(function(event){
    $('#index2').trigger('click');
});

$('#index2').click(function(event){
   alert("Hello");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 id="index1">
Index 1
</h2>


<h4 id="index2">
Index 2
</h4>
```